# My player idle animation is playing but I cant see it when testing the game

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender, animator

So I separately imported the player mesh and the animation from blender. Everything is the same except, if I exported the character(mesh) again with the animation (I exported the animation only because as I said I already had the mesh) it will be a bit bigger than the one I use. I created the Animator and hookup the animation and when I play the game, I can see the Idle animation looping over and over again in the Animator tab (which is perfect). However, I don't see the animation playing on my mesh. I can provide you with additional information if it helps.